# `.one` function is attached multiple times

Tags: jquery

I have a function, that binds a function via `.one('click'` to an element:

```
function apply() {
    jQuery('.delete-item').one('click', function() {
        jQuery('body').LoadingOverlay('show');
        var id = jQuery(this).closest('.item').data('item-id');
        delete_item(this, id);
    });
}
```

Then the apply function is called multiple times (because there are new elements in the dom). But although I use the `.one` instead of `.on`, the click function gets attached three times:
[image]

When I remove the listeners manually in chrome, it works fine.

Why is the listener applied multiple times?

Comment: It is applied once to every `.delete-item`, if you have multiple items and only want this to run once altogether then just use `.off()` to kill it. If you look at the documentation `Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.`

Comment: No it's fine that it's applied to every element, but it's not fine that it's applied to every element three times

Comment: Well then you need to post more code on how the function `apply()` is called. Every time apply is called, the handler will get attached, since there is no issue with the `.one()` the problem must be elsewhere. Perhaps you can delegate the event to a parent so you can just bind `.one()` once and not have the need to bind every time `apply` is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.one()` doesn't guarantee that only one event handler will be called for a particular event; it guarantees that *this particular* event handler will only run once.

In the sample below if you click the "apply" button four times, you will call `apply()` four times, which will attach four `.one('click')` handlers to the other button.  If you click that button, you'll see it runs four times.  If you click it again, it will run zero times (because each of the four events expired after its first use.)

```js
function apply() {
  console.log("Calling apply");
  $('.foo').one('click', function() {
    console.log("CLICKED");
  });
  
}

$('.apply').on('click', apply);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="foo">Click me to trigger .one</button>

<button class="apply">Click me to apply()</button>
```

Instead of running your `apply()` function which attaches event handlers to every `.delete-item` on the page every time you add stuff to the DOM, you could attach single event handlers only to the newly-added item.

But what would probably be easiest is to, at document ready, attach a single *delegated* event to the body or a convenient parent element that will handle the event for any child `.delete-item` (even if that item didn't exist when the delegated event was created):

```js
$('body').on('click', '.delete-item', function() {
  // ...
  var id = $(this).closest('.item').data('item-id');
  // delete_item(this, id);
  console.log("Clicked ", id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-item-id="1"><button class="delete-item">delete</button></div>
<div class="item" data-item-id="2"><button class="delete-item">delete</button></div>
<div class="item" data-item-id="3"><button class="delete-item">delete</button></div>
```